# How to mock views for unit testing in android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a helper class that I am using for TextInputEditText field validation in my application. It takes in an array of TextInputEditText with different tags. Firstly it sieve anyone that is empty and then proceed to validate them based on their different tag.
I want to be able to test the class and pass array of TextInputEditText with tags as a parameter but finding it hard to mock an TextInputEditText.

```
class Validation private constructor(
    var respond:TextInputEditText,
    vararg edits: TextInputEditText
) {

    class Builder(
        var email: TextInputEditText? = null,
        var password: TextInputEditText? = null,
        var phoneNumber: TextInputEditText? = null,
        var respond:TextInputEditText?=null,
        vararg var edits: TextInputEditText

    ) {

        fun getEmptyField(edits: Array<out TextInputEditText>): Builder = apply {
            this.edits = edits
            for (edit in edits) {
                when {
                    edit.text?.isEmpty() == true -> {
                        edit.error = "${edit.tag} is required"
                        this.respond = edit
                        return@apply
                    }
                    edit.tag.toString().contains("email", true) -> {
                        this.email = edit
                    }
                    edit.tag.toString().contains("password", true) -> {
                        this.password = edit
                    }
                    edit.tag.toString().contains("phone", true) -> {
                        this.phoneNumber = edit
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        fun email() = apply {
            val emailPattern = Regex("""^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*${'$'}""")
            val matchedEmail = emailPattern.matches(this.email?.text.toString())
            if(matchedEmail){
                return@apply
            }
            else{
                this.respond = email
                this.respond?.error = "Invalid"
                return@apply
            }
        }
        fun password() = apply {
            val passwordPattern = Regex("""^[a-zA-Z0-9@$!.%*#?&]{6,}$""")
            val matchedPassword = passwordPattern.matches(this.password?.text.toString())
            if(matchedPassword){
                return@apply
            }
            else{
                this.respond = password
                this.respond?.error = "Invalid"
                return@apply
            }
        }
        fun phone() = apply {
            val phonePattern = Regex("""^(80|70|90|81)([12356709])\d{7}$""")
            val matchedPhone = phonePattern.matches(this.phoneNumber.toString())
            if(matchedPhone){
                return@apply
            }
            else{
                this.respond = phoneNumber
                this.respond?.error = "Invalid"
                return@apply
            }

        }
        fun build():Validation? {
            val listOfDefaulters = arrayListOf<TextInputEditText>()
            for (edit in this.edits){
                if (edit.error != null){
                    listOfDefaulters.add(edit)
                    this.respond = listOfDefaulters[0]
                    this.respond!!.error = "Invalid"
                }
            }
           return respond?.let { Validation(it, *edits) }
        }
    }

}
```

How can I test this class and pass the stub.

Comment: if you're struggling to test this class, you should consider how _testable_ it is. consider why are you passing in android components to (what could basically be) just a java class

Comment: I thought of this too. Does it mean that there is no way to mock an android component for this purpose

Comment: It's possible to unit-test UI-bound logic with Robolectric, but the way it's done is neither with mocking nor with real classes. It adds complexity and slows down test execution, so it should be used if there's absolutely no other way to do otherwise (or with instrumented testing). In your case, it seems the class can work with just strings; then a simple adapter can pass strings from TextInputEditTexts to the class and vice-versa.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be validating UI - you should be validating ViewModels that drive the UI. You would have a ViewModel that has all the data that would fill the TextInputLayouts and write your logic in there, then write unit tests against that, without worrying about Android views.

Comment: Yeah I think I would just revert to using string to remove the complexity. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a work around. This might help someone else. You can find the code below.

Basically what I did was to pass in a pair with custom class to simulate the edit-text and corresponding optional edit text. With that I was able to test the class with only the custom class.

```
/**
 * @author Abdulrasaq Durosomo
 * @param respond
 * @param edits
 */
class Validation private constructor(
    var respond: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>,
    vararg var edits: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>
) {

    class Builder(
        var emailPair: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>? = null,
        var passwordPair: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>? = null,
        var phoneNumberPair: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>? = null,
        var respond: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>? = null,
        vararg var fieldPairList: Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>

    ) {

        /**
         * @param edits
         * This separates field based on their tag and also rejects empty field
         */
        fun separateFieldByTag(edits: List<Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>>): Builder = apply {
            this.fieldPairList = edits.toTypedArray()
            for (edit in edits) {
                when {
                    edit.first.text.isEmpty() -> {
                        edit.first.error = "${edit.first.tag} is required"
                        edit.second?.error = "${edit.first.tag} is required"
                        this.respond = edit
                        return@apply
                    }
                    edit.first.tag.toString().contains("email", true) -> {
                        this.emailPair = edit
                    }
                    edit.first.tag.toString().contains("password", true) -> {
                        this.passwordPair = edit
                    }
                    edit.first.tag.toString().contains("phone", true) -> {
                        this.phoneNumberPair = edit
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Validate email address
         */
        fun email() = apply {
            val emailPattern = Regex("""^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*${'$'}""")
            val matchedEmail = emailPattern.matches(this.emailPair?.first?.text.toString())
            if (matchedEmail) {
                return@apply
            } else {
                this.respond = emailPair
                this.respond?.first?.error = "Invalid"
                this.respond?.second?.error = "Invalid"
                return@apply
            }
        }

        /**
         * Validate password
         */
        fun password() = apply {
            val passwordPattern = Regex("""^[a-zA-Z0-9@$!.%*#?&]{6,15}$""")
            val matchedPassword = passwordPattern.matches(this.passwordPair?.first?.text.toString())
            if (matchedPassword) {
                return@apply
            } else {
                this.respond = passwordPair
                this.respond?.first?.error = "Invalid"
                this.respond?.second?.error = "Invalid"
                return@apply
            }
        }

        /**
         * Validate phone number
         */
        fun phone() = apply {
            val phonePattern = Regex("""^(80|70|90|81)([12356709])\d{7}$""")
            val matchedPhone = phonePattern.matches(this.phoneNumberPair?.first?.text.toString())
            if (matchedPhone) {
                return@apply
            } else {
                this.respond = phoneNumberPair
                this.respond?.first?.error = "Invalid"
                this.respond?.second?.error = "Invalid"
                return@apply
            }
        }

        /**
         * Build validation
         */
        fun build(): Validation? {
            val listOfDefaulters = arrayListOf<Pair<CustomEditTextField, TextInputEditText?>?>()
            for (edit in this.fieldPairList) {
                if (edit.first.error != "") {
                    listOfDefaulters.add(edit)
                    this.respond = listOfDefaulters[0]
                    this.respond!!.second?.error = "Invalid"
                }
            }
            return respond?.let { Validation(it, *fieldPairList) }
        }
    }
}
```